# Having trouble rebinding $request->setUserResolver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm attempting to rebind what `$request->user()` returns, and having poked through the built in authentication code, I found a service using `app->rebinding` to `request->setUserResolver` is how it's done? I tried it myself, with no luck. I created a service (well, coopted AuthServiceProvider, and changed the register to:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->rebinding('request', function ($app, $request) {
        $request->setUserResolver(function () use ($app) {
            $token = $this->request->bearerToken();
            dd($token);
            // error_log($token);
            return array('user' => 1);
        });
    });
}
```

Ignoring the dd, which is there to test, how can I find where I'm going wrong? I even found a SO answer that seems to indicate this is the way to go but nothing gets dumped, nothing gets logged (when error log isn't commented out) and dumping `$request->user()` in my controller just returns null.

I know I can use the built in auth/guard setup, but I figured since I'm not using most of what the auth/guard setup has, why not try to learn and set it up myself? Of course, so far I've gotten nowhere. I'm going to fall back to using the built-in stuff, but I'd like to learn and improve.

As I realized it may make a difference, I'm running Lumen 5.4.

Comment: Did you add your new service provider to `config/app.php` in `'providers'`?

Comment: I actually just deleted the content of the existing `AuthServiceProvider` and wrote that into the `register()`. Didn't think that would be an issue?

Comment: Oh, I thought you copied **AuthserviceProvider** into new provider... Not an issue. also check [How to bind user object to request in a middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414776/how-to-bind-user-object-to-request-in-a-middleware). Could point you to right direction

Comment: Thanks. I ran into that earlier, and I guess I should test that out myself. As mentioned, hoping to figure out what I'm doing wrong as much for learning as anything else.

Comment: Can you provide minimum code git repo to debug the issue?

Comment: Sure, though right now it's just a default Lumen 5.4 install with the AuthServiceProvider `register` function replaced with above and the `boot` function cleared.

Answer (score 0):

In Lumen, your `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` class comes by default with

```
public function boot()
{
    // Here you may define how you wish users to be authenticated for your Lumen
    // application. The callback which receives the incoming request instance
    // should return either a User instance or null. You're free to obtain
    // the User instance via an API token or any other method necessary.
    $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
        if ($request->input('api_token')) {
            return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the place to define the user resolution logic. The rebinding you were registering in the `register` method was being supeseded by this one.

Just uncomment the `$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);` line in `bootstrap/app.php` to register your provider; don't modify the code in the `vendor` folder (if I understood correctly you were doing that).

---

*Update*

I now see what you mean, although I'm not sure it is really too much "load" for the auth/guard method.
However, in the interest of creating a minimal implementation, I think the solution would be overriding the `prepareRequest` method of the `Application` class.

In `bootstrap/app.php` replace

```
$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

with

```
$app = new class (realpath(__DIR__.'/../')) extends Laravel\Lumen\Application {
    protected function prepareRequest(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
    {
        if (! $request instanceof Illuminate\Http\Request) {
            $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::createFromBase($request);
        }

        $request->setUserResolver(function () use ($request) {
            return $request->bearerToken();
        })->setRouteResolver(function () {
            return $this->currentRoute;
        });

        return $request;
    }
};
```

This way you can have the simple resolution logic for getting the bearer token (don't include the AuthServiceProvider then).

(This requires PHP 7 anonymous classes; alternatively just extend to a regular class).

Comment: Well, `echo`s, `dd`s, `error_log`s inside the function never even trigger, so it's not even at the point of if there is a request object. It never actually gets inside the function. As I mentioned, I copied it from the built in `AuthService` schema. If I can get into the function, even if the request object isn't there, I can extract the header value I need.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but as I mentioned at the end of the question, I know I can use the built in auth/guard methods, but I'm looking to learn more about how Laravel/Lumen are working under the hood. I traced the `viaRequest` back through vendor, and found that it's rebinding `setUserResolver`, so wanted to try that myself. I'm only changing things in vendor in so much to debug how it's working. The built in auth/guard does far more than I need, so I wanted to learn so I could help reduce the overall load. I'm copying code out of vendor to create my own AuthServiceProvider.

Comment: Thanks so much for the expanded answer! I'll definitely take a deep look. You're right in that "reduce load" in this case probably doesn't mean much. I was more interested in the learning. I still would like to figure out why the built in AuthService functionality worked with a rebind that worked while mine didn't, but this is a good chunk to chew on. I'll test at earliest possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You **do not need** to change the `register()` function.
Just uncomment the following lines in `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
$app->withEloquent();
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
```

And in `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php->boot()`, it has default method to retrieve the authenticated user.

```
$this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
    if ($request->input('api_token')) {
        return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
    }
});
```

> You may use an API token in the request headers or query string, a bearer token on the request, or using any other approach your application requires.

After that, you may retrieve the authenticated user like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$app->get('/post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'auth', function (Request $request, $id) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user = $request->user();

    //
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned in my answer, I already know I can do this through the built in Auth/Guard system; I've been through the docs and already set it up this way. I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of Laravel/Lumen, and so am trying to extrapolate how the Auth system does it, which appears to be how I'm doing it above, except my method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `rebinding` method will add an additional `reboundCallbacks` which this callback will be triggered right after the abstract is rebound. As long as your abstract is not rebound, the `reboundCallbacks` are not called. So, you can simply rebound your abstract, like so:

```
$this->app->rebinding('request', function ($app, $request) {
    $request->setUserResolver(function () use ($app) {
        $token = $this->request->bearerToken();

        dd($token);

        // do the rest
    });
});

// REBOUND HERE
$this->app->instance('request', $this->app->make('request'));

// TEST
// $this->app->make('request')->user(); // output is $token
```

Try uncomment the rebound line above, your `dd` will not called at all.

### Extra

You can use `refresh` method (to register `reboundCallbacks`) combined with `extend` method (to rebound) for cleaner code:

```
public function register()
{
    parent::register();

    $this->app->refresh('request', $this, 'overrideUserResolver');

    // REBOUND HERE, JUST ANOTHER WAY TO REBOUND
    $this->app->extend('request', function ($request) { return $request; });

    // TEST
    $this->app->make('request')->user();
}

public function overrideUserResolver($request)
{
    $request->setUserResolver(function ($guard = null) use ($request) {
        $token = $request->bearerToken();

        dd($token);

        // do the rest
    });
}
```