# Laravel Auth User Object on all responses

Tags: laravel

I want to append an auth user object (if available) to all responses on my Laravel app.

I have the following code here as Auth User object

```
  "user": {
    "name": "mike",
    "has_active_subscription": false,
    "is_onboarded": false,
    "email_verified": false
  }
```

Is there a middleware approaching to attaching this to all responses?

Answer (score 1):

You can make middleware or use trait here.
I am doing it with trait ,

```
namespace App\Traits;
            
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
            
    trait Response{
                
        protected function response($response) {
            //import auth above
            $user = Auth::user();
            if (isset($user)) {
                $response = [...$response, ...$user];
            }
        
        return response()->json($response);
    }
}

Now make a parent controller BaseController

class BaseController {
   use Response;
}

Now just extends your other controller with BaseController and you can use response() method easily in that controller too.
```

Answer (score 0):

but I think this will help:

1. An assumption - I believe you are saying that yes, this line will get you the user you want:

   ```
   $user = $team->User()->first();
   ```

and you merely want to bind it to the request so that you can access this user later in your app via:

```
   $request->user()
```

2. If this is true, then all I did was simplify the code you provided to add:

   ```
   $request->merge(['user' => $user ]);
   ```

//add this

```
$request->setUserResolver(function () use ($user) {
    return $user;
});
```

// if you dump() you can now see the $request has it

```
dump($request->user());

return $next($request);
```

I also `$request->user()` in the route closure, and it is there.

The app rebinding was a little strange to me, and didn't seem necessary. I'm not sure that anything would really need this for what you are doing.

Also follow this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414776/how-to-bind-user-object-to-request-in-a-middleware) It will help you more.